# how can i plot stacked columns and a single column in highcharts together?(multi Stacked)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, stacked

my data is something like below.

i want to show them in one single chart in `highcharts`.

```
category [jack jane julie john]
```

i have 3 series of grades like this:

```
homework  [2 1 2 3]

midterm   [5 4 6 6]

final exam[10 9 11 10]
```

i want them  to be stacked.
and their ages:

```
ages      [18 22 17 24]
```

my problem is i know how to stack and know how to plot columns but not they together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set different stacking groups:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['jack', 'jane', 'julie', 'john']
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'Grades'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Age'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: [
        // first stack 
        {
            data: [2, 1, 2, 3],
            stack: 0,
            yAxis: 0
        }, {
            data: [5, 4, 6, 6],
            stack: 0,
            yAxis: 0
        }, {
            data: [10, 9, 11, 10],
            stack: 0,
            yAxis: 0
        },
        // second stack 
        {
            data: [18, 22, 17, 24],
            stack: 1,
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhSrh/